# mysql query for 3 tables, join or union which one is best to calculate balance?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

With the following 3 tables, how to calculate the stock balance for million records in a best/faster way ?!
As my experience, using join can take less than 0.1 sec but not the final result,
using union can got the final result but it takes 1x sec...

```
stocktable
stid    productid   qty
1   1   100
2   2   200

sellstable
sellid  stid    qty
1   1   50
2   1   30

scraptable
scrapid stid    qty
1   1   10
2   1   5
3   2   100
```

```
SELECT
    a.stid,
    qty,
    sellid,
    b.qty,
    scrapid,
    c.qty
FROM
    stocktable AS a
LEFT JOIN sellstable AS b ON a.stid = b.stid
LEFT JOIN scraptable AS c ON a.stid = c.stid
```

---

```
1   100 1   50  1   10
1   100 1   50  1   5
1   100 2   30  1   10
1   100 2   30  1   5
2   200 null    null    3   100
```

this is fast when using join for the inner query, but how to sum up the balance...

added info:

```
the result should be
1   5
2   100
```

thanks!

Comment: How can you get a balance without a price?

Comment: hi, thanks for comment. only balance qty is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally need all the columns in your query, along with the sum of the three qty fields, then you can do `SUM(a.qty+b.qty+c.qty)`, but it's hard to figure exactly what you are looking for.  Is there a particular key in those tables that you want to group on? Do you need sellid and scrapid at all?

Comment: Hello muffinista, sellid and scrpid is no need for this query I think. I had also tried and sucess by using subquery for each required field, but I think using JOIN should be the fast way...but how to do it?!

Comment: Are your quantities correct in the expected results above? I don't see how the quantity for stid=1 could possibly be 5, but maybe I am missing something.